# Remove duplicate dictionaries from a list and subtract value of keys of duplicate element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts, and I'd like to remove the dicts with identical key and subtract the value pairs.

For this list:

```
[{'chair': 4}, {'tv': 5}, {'chair': 3}, {'tv': 2}, {'laptop': 2}]
```

I'd like to return this:

```
[{'chair': 1}, {'tv': 3}, {'laptop': 2}]
```

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte You can't have duplicate keys in a `dict`

Comment: Please edit your post and show us the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example you already have. This helps us to address your problem more closely

Comment: Wouldn't just one single dict of key-value pairs be better to begin with? IMHO: Having single item dicts makes no sense.

Comment: Criticism of data structure aside: what should happen if there are **more** than two dicts with identical keys?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog : `...and subtract the value pairs.`

Comment: @Powertieke if there are three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this, creating an intermediate dict for efficiency:

```
dicts_list = [{'chair': 4}, {'tv': 5}, {'chair': 3}, {'tv': 2}, {'laptop': 2}]

out = {}
for d in dicts_list:
    for key, val in d.items():
       if key in out:
           out[key] -= val
       else:
           out[key] = val

out_list = [ {key:val} for key, val in out.items()]

print(out_list)
# [{'tv': 3}, {'chair': 1}, {'laptop': 2}]
```

But you might be interested in this intermediate dict as output:

```
print(out)
# {'tv': 3, 'chair': 1, 'laptop': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... and how to do the same thing with 2 dictionary. like  c={'laptop': 2, 'chair': 4, 'tv': 3} and c1={'keyboard': 1, 'laptop': 2, 'chair': 4, 'tv': 4,'plant':2} and output should be d= {'keyboard':1,'tv:1','plant:2'}

Comment: Just set `dict_list = [c, c1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict` from collections might come in handy. This solution will cover the cases where there are more than 2 dicts of the same key in the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
ls = defaultdict(list)
d = [{'chair': 4}, {'tv': 5}, {'chair': 3}, {'tv': 2}, {'laptop': 2}]


# Creating a list of all values under one key

for dic in d:
    for k in dic:
            ls[k].append(dic[k])

print(ls)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'chair': [4, 3], 'tv': [5, 2], 'laptop': [2]})

# safe proofing for negative values on subtraction    
for k in ls:
    ls[k].sort(reverse=True)
    ls[k] = ls[k][0] - sum(ls[k][1:])

print(ls)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'chair': 1, 'tv': 3, 'laptop': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet is using nothing but standard modules:

```
a= [{'chair': 4}, {'tv': 5}, {'chair': 3}, {'tv': 2}, {'laptop': 2}]

print("Input:", a)

b=dict()
for element in a:
    for k,v in element.items():
        try:
          # you didn't specify the subtracted element order,   
          # so I'm subtracting BIGGER from SMALLER using simple abs() :)
          b[k] = abs(b[k] - v) 
        except:
          b[k] = v

print("Output:", b)

# restore original structure
c = [ dict({item}) for item in b.items() ]

print("Output:", c)
```

And demo:

```
('Input:', [{'chair': 4}, {'tv': 5}, {'chair': 3}, {'tv': 2}, {'laptop': 2}])
('Output:', {'tv': 3, 'chair': 1, 'laptop': 2})
('Output:', [{'tv': 3}, {'chair': 1}, {'laptop': 2}])
```

**EDIT: Added the secondary out put C to restructure B similar to A**

Comment: OP wanted to subtract, not add the values. Even after making that change, how is your answer different from Thierry's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459576/6775799.

Comment: Yeah, I had just submitted and then saw that I used wrong operator. By the time I fixed it now, You had commented and also somebody else had replied. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `defaultdict` of lists, then use a list comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    k, v = next(iter(d.items()))
    dd[k].append(v)

res = [{k: v if len(v) == 1 else v[0] - sum(v[1:])} for k, v in dd.items()]

print(res)
# [{'chair': 1}, {'tv': 3}, {'laptop': [2]}]
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2 dicts with the same key in the list?

Comment: Thanks. So now there are 4 answers in total, making two pairs on the basis of similarity.

Comment: @RahulChawla, Yup, there are slight differences between ours, but agree conceptually similar. Variety is good :)

Comment: Also, add an `abs()` because you don't know which value will be greatest among all dicts, which might result in a negative value. Variety is good indeed! :)

Comment: @RahulChawla, IMO, that's an extra assumption that needs clarification in the question. Negative numbers may be fine. These numbers might be changes rather than quantities; we really don't know.

Comment: @RahulChawla Kindly reload the page. You should be able to see mine answers OPs question right now :)